# Copy from 2 workbooks into 1 workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Getting an

> run time error 1004

when trying to copy from two different workbooks into the same workbook

I am copying certain cells from two worksheets into one worksheet.  I have tried different several ways to get other errors so I am back to this one.

```
Sub Range_Copy_Examples()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wbData As Range
Dim wbData1 As Range
Dim wbExtract As Range
Dim wbExtract1 As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbData = wb.Worksheets("GAI").Range("A1")
    Set wbExtract = wb.Worksheets("Report").Range("A3:I3")

    wbData.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wbExtract

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wbData1 = wb1.Worksheets("FUND").Range("H1")
    Set wbExtract1 = wb.Worksheets("Report").Range("J3:K3")

    wbData1.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wbExtract1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work with both workbooks set to be ActiweWorkbook, insted try change names  to ThisWorkbook on one where you store this code, and fill the name with extension of the other workbook you are trying to copy from.

```
Sub Range_Copy_Examples()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wbData As Range
Dim wbData1 As Range
Dim wbExtract As Range
Dim wbExtract1 As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbData = wb.Worksheets("GAI").Range("A1")
Set wbExtract = wb.Worksheets("Report").Range("A3:I3")

wbData.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wbExtract

Set wb1 = Workbooks("TheOtherWorkbook.xls")
Set wbData1 = wb1.Worksheets("FUND").Range("H1")
Set wbExtract1 = wb.Worksheets("Report").Range("J3:K3")

wbData1.CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wbExtract1
```

End Sub